# Ignore terms in the equation of motion

Tags: scaling

While working on a problem relative to particles motion, I ended up with the following second order nonlinear differential equation:
$$\tag{1} \ddot{y}(t)+\frac{y(t)}{b^2}\left(a-\frac{\dot{y}(t)^2}{2}\right)=0,$$
where $[a]=m^2~s^{-2}$, $[b]=m$, $y$ is the particle's position, such that, $[y]=m$ and, consequently, $[\dot{y}]=m~s^{-1}$.

In general I can't solve this equation so I thought that I could solve for a simplified case: when the quantity $a$ is much bigger than the particle's velocity, throughout the particle's motion. Such that Eq.$(1)$ is given by
$$\ddot{y}(t)+\frac{a~y(t)}{b^2}=0,$$
the harmonic oscillator equation. My question is: can I do this? If not, do I need to [scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization) Eq.$(1)$ first? I ask the last question because of what is done to get the [Reynolds number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number#Derivation) for the Navier-Stokes equations...

Comment: The dimensionalities you have given do not seem to equate. $[\ddot{y}]=m s^{-2}$ where as $[y a b^{-2}]=m^3s^2$.

Comment: @ComptonScattering My mistake. I don't know what I was thinking. Maybe I copy pasted something wrongly. Either way, just edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: @PML: you can solve the simplified equation easily. You can thus compute the velocity at all time and compare it to $a$. Depending on you initial conditions, you can verify if the  assumption is correct a posteriori. If not, maybe you have to do the opposite assumptions.

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/81691/2451

Comment: Indeed, Adam's guidance is correct. It is notable that in this case, since the solution to the SHO leaves the oscillation amplitude as a free parameter, the restriction $\sqrt{a} \gg \dot{y}$ becomes a constraint on the value of this parameter, rather than on the validity of the general approach.